# VBScript error 5 trying to compute sha512 with 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed'

Tags: vbscript, sha512

I am trying to write a piece of code in VBScript to compute the
SHA512 value for a given file. According to MSFT documentation
the ComputeHash method of the SHA512Managed object requires a 
Byte array as input. So I used ADODB to read the input file which
SHA512 value is to be computed (Because, AFAIK, there is no way 
to build a Byte array in VBScript). However I get a runtime error 5, 
'Invalid procedure call or argument' when calling the method. The 
variable bar in the code below is of type Byte() - VBScript says.

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong ?

Code :

```
Option Explicit
'
'
'
Dim scs, ado            
Dim bar, hsh

Set scs = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

ado.type = 1 ' TypeBinary
ado.open
ado.LoadFromFile WScript.ScriptFullName
bar = ado.Read
ado.Close

MsgBox TypeName(bar) & "/" & LenB(bar) & "/" & Len(bar),,"Box 1" 
' Displays : "Byte()/876/438"

On Error Resume Next
' Attempt 1
Set hsh = scs.ComputeHash(bar)
MsgBox Hex(Err.Number) & "/" & Err.Description,,"Set hsh = " 
' Displays : "5/Invalid procedure call or argument"

' Attempt 2
hsh = scs.ComputeHash(bar)
MsgBox Hex(Err.Number) & "/" & Err.Description,,"hsh = "     
' Displays : "5/Invalid procedure call or argument"

MsgBox TypeName(scs),,"scs" ' Displays : "SHA512Managed"

Set ado = Nothing
Set scs = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: bar is referencing the script you are running.  Do you get the same error referencing a file that is not in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
hsh = scs.ComputeHash_2((bar))
```

(no set, _2 suffix not to pick the other ComputeHash method, pass by value ())

see [here](https://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/replicating-phps-sha1-in-vbscript/).

Comment: Thanks a lot and Merci beaucoup Ekkehard. It works fine.

Comment: And thanks again for the link. The pointed code is sober, clear and efficient.