# "Invalid procedure call or argument" when calling a sub without parenthesing one parameter

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic, pass-by-value, comvisible

I wrote a COM-Visible DLL with this piece of code (VB.NET)

```
' .NET Class with implementing an interface to make it visible
Public Class VisibleClass
    Public Sub callableSub(ByVal names As ACustomCollection, _
                           Optional ByVal doSomething As Boolean = True) _
        Implements IVisibleClass.visibleCallableSub
        Me.doSub(names.process, doSomething)
    End Sub
End Class

' Interface for COM-visibility
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface IVisibleClass
    Sub visibleCallableSub(ByVal names As ACustomCollection, _
                           Optional ByVal doSomething As Boolean = True)
End Interface
```

Here is also the ASP web page creating the object and invoking its methods :

```
' stuff.asp
Dim visibleObject
Dim aCustomCollection
Set visibleObject = getNewVisibleInstance (aCollection)
Set aCustomCollection = createEmptyCollection

aCustomCollection.add someStuffs
aCustomCollection.add otherStuffs
aCustomCollection.add lastStuffs

' These calls work:
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub(aCustomCollection)
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub(aCustomCollection), False
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub(aCustomCollection), True
Call document.fetchPropertyCollection ((properties), false)

' These ones don't:
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub someparams
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub someparams, False
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub someparams, True
Call document.fetchPropertyCollection (properties, false)
```

Non working calls produce the following error :

> Invalid procedure call or argument

I don't understand why I have to put parenthesis. I know this tells the interpreter to make a copy before passing theme, but not why it's mandatory.

**Note :**  It's the same issue than this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747341), i.e. about passing a reference where a copy is required. However, the question was told like it's due to "passing the return value of another function", which make it harder to reach through research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid procedure call" error when passing a variable as argument vs. passing the return value of another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747341/invalid-procedure-call-error-when-passing-a-variable-as-argument-vs-passing-t)

Comment: @Lankymart It's the same issue - passing a reference where a copy is required. However, the question mentions "vs. passing the return value of another function" which could be misleading... So I don't know what to do...

Comment: Also don't take downvotes personally, they're not a personal attack towards you or anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the called Sub/Function asks for a **value** (By**Value**), you can't pass a reference ('pointer'). Putting the 'make a **copy**' parentheses around the argument makes sure the called Sub/Function gets a **value**.

To make your intention explicit, you should write:

```
visibleObject.visibleCallableSub (aCustomCollection), False
```

Cf. [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613462/603855), [parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622374/603855), [adventures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/).

Comment: I updated by adding two lines with a `Call`... A `Call` forces a copy, right ? If so, why do I need to put parenthesis even in this case ?

Comment: The (silly) Call keyword just allows you to use parameter list parentheses; it does **not** copy. Follow the second link to read about different kind of () and their function.

Comment: *“(silly) Call keyword”* - Why is it silly? The `Call` statement is very useful, it makes identifying procedures in code a breeze and allows `Sub` procedures to be called using parentheses. Used it for years and never had a problem, the only reason it would be silly is if the tendency is to write sloppy code that is only comprehensible to you. Each to their own I guess.